# return NULL instead of std::string C++

Tags: c++, return

I have this function:

```
std::string SWindows::PRecv(int rc, std::string* ip);
```

In this function, in some case I return NULL and the code compile (IDE : VS 2012).
For me, NULL it's not a std::string object so we can't write that.

So why it's correct to return NULL when the return of the function is a std::string ?

Comment: The compiler is probably choosing the string(const char*) constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value `NULL` is equivalent to `0` in C++ and `0` is a perfectly valid `char const*` constant. The string class has a non-`explicit` constructor taking `char const*`, i.e. the compiler will compile the code but it won't work: that is, although the compiler excepts the code, it is undefined behavior.

Looking at the definition in C++11 I don't see a `delete`d overload taking a `std::nullptr_t`, i.e., it will also compile when converting from a `nullptr`. I would have hoped that there would be a `delete`d overload taking a `std::nullptr_t` which would allow the compiler to catch the situation, at least, when passing `nullptr`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the downvote! Can you please explain why the answer was downvoted? Note the "... but it won't work." (I'll be more clear about that in a moment, though).

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote.  This answer seems correct and hits on the important points.  The only problem I can see is that the "won't work" may not be as obvious at a glance, so perhaps superficial readers are assuming the answer says `string(0)` is okay, when it's actually UB.

Comment: Huh, why would anyone downvote this? And then there's two of you? I'd love to know where you disagree with @Dietmar, because you're wrong (whoever you are).

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson: thanks. I updated with a bit of clarification.

Comment: I downvoted, probably without reading very carefully, because the first thing I saw was that NULL is valid. I'll reverse. @stefan: I'm obviously not "wrong" if you look at my answer ;)

Comment: As a side-note, perhaps `string` should acquire this constructor declaration: `basic_string(void const *)=delete;` --- I think that would match `string(NULL)` and `string(0)` so that these uses would fail.  (Just an idea off the top of my head; don't eviscerate me if it has an obvious flaw.)

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson: I'd think it is more important to get a constructor for `std::nullptr_t` to have `std::string(nullptr)` fail! Looking at the latest draft I see that relevant (21.4.2 paragraph 8) was meddled with: it now read "Requires: `s` points to an array of at least `traits::length(s) + 1` elements of `charT.`" I'm not sure how that improves anything...

Comment: Does `NULL` prefer to be cast to `std::nullptr_t` over `const char*`?

Comment: @DietmarKühl, I think it would be fine to add both declarations.  But perhaps just adding the `void const *` `delete`d overload would make `string(nullptr)` ambiguous, which may accomplish the same objective.

Comment: @Yakk: It seems using `NULL` would be ambiguous if there were constructors taking both `std::nullptr_t` and `char const*`. That would be an acceptable outcome, too: have a `delete`d constructor taking a `std::nullptr_t`. That should really be a defect...

Comment: @Yakk, I'm not entirely sure, but I think `0` will not convert to a `nullptr_t` at all.  I think that's one of its features, so you can write `void foo(nullptr_t); void foo(int); foo(0);` and expect the `int` overload to be selected.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson: It seems `0` has no preference for `char const*` or `std::nullptr_t`: `void f(std::nullptr_t); void f(char const*); int main() { f(0); }` results in an ambiguous call according to clang and gcc (haven't chased through the standard whether that is the correct result, though).

Comment: @DietmarKühl, yeah, I just tried it with GCC 4.6 and got the same answer.  In fact, according to my GCC tests, adding either overload (`nullptr_t` or `void const *`) would solve the problem by making `NULL` and `0` calls ambiguous.

Comment: Well why would `std::nullptr_t` be special in any way? Afaik, the compiler doesn't have preferences regarding types. I'm curious: is there any situation in which an "ambiguity" is resolved by a language "preference" the compiler has to obey? That would be weird, imho.

Comment: @stefan: `std::nullptr_t` is somewhat special: it isn't just some weird pointer type. The conversions to and from this type are deliberately not exactly as those of pointers. However, it seems you can convert `0` to `std::nullptr_t`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Right, but in terms of the type system it's not special in any way. It's as good as a user defined type.

Answer (score 5):

What you're doing is constructing a `std::string` from a `char const*` equal to `0` (or `NULL`).

This is actually prohibited by the standard:

> `[C++11: 21.4.2/9]` Requires: `s` shall not be a null pointer

However, GCC is extra-kind to you and [does checks to make it a no-op](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.0/basic__string_8tcc-source.html#l00225). It is not required to and you shouldn't ever rely on this.

Comment: Wow! That's kinda dangerous! But the original code is already broken, so I guess it's fine...